# Create new divs and select boxes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying create some divs with select boxes.

The code is working if you change number of children (see example below - the last one with 0 as selected), and is creating new div with select boxes depends on value of select box.

But if number of rooms is greater than 1 then it stops working. And I got no error from js on dev tools.

Also you can see I have some code as commented to use it for each room on the children select options.

1. **What am I doing wrong and the select box is not working when the rooms are more than 1?**
2. **Is there a better way to make it work with a for loop instead of going as Kids Age 1 Room - Kids Age 2 Room - Kids Age 3 Room ?**

Please any feedback would be helpful.

Also excuse my language for any mistakes :D

```js
document.getElementById('search_rooms_select').addEventListener('change', function(){ 
    var container = document.getElementById('container');    
    container.innerHTML = '';
    var n = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.options.length; ++i){
        if(this.options[i].selected){
            n = ~~this.options[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }    
    for(var i = 1; i <= n; ++i){ 
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
        newDiv.id = 'element-' + i; 
        newDiv.innerHTML = "<div class='col-xs-12 col-md-12' id='room-"+i+"'><div class='col-xs-4 col-md-4'><label>Room "+i+":</label></div><div class='col-xs-8 col-md-8 paddinglr'><div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6'><select name='adultsTotalRoom"+i+"' class='form-control' id='adults-"+i+"'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2' selected>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option></select></div><div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6'><select name='childrenTotalRoom1' class='form-control' id='children-"+i+"'><option value='0' selected>0</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option></select></div></div><div id='kidssection"+i+"'></div></div>";

        container.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
}); 
document.getElementById('search_rooms_select').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

//Kids Age 1 Room
document.getElementById('children-1').addEventListener('change', function(){ 
    var ks1 = document.getElementById('kidssection1');    
    ks1.innerHTML = ''; 
    var m = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.options.length; ++i){
        if(this.options[i].selected){
            m = ~~this.options[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }    
    for(var i = 1; i <= m; ++i){ 
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
        newDiv.id = 'elementm-' + i; 
        newDiv.innerHTML = "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3'><small>Child "+i+" Age</small><select name='children1age"+i+"' class='form-control' id='children1age"+i+"'><option value='0'>0</option></select></div>";
        ks1.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
}); 
document.getElementById('children-1').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));


//////Kids Age 2 Room
//document.getElementById('children-2').addEventListener('change', function(){ 
//    var ks2 = document.getElementById('kidssection2');    
//    ks2.innerHTML = ''; 
//    var m1 = 1;
//    for(var i = 0; i < this.options.length; ++i){
//        if(this.options[i].selected){
//            m1 = ~~this.options[i].value;
//            break;
//        }
//    }    
//    for(var i = 1; i <= m1; ++i){ 
//        var newDiva = document.createElement('div'); 
//        newDiva.id = 'elementm1-' + i; 
//        newDiva.innerHTML = "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3'><select name='children1age"+i+"' class='form-control' id='children2age"+i+"'><option value='0'>0</option></select></div>";
//        ks2.appendChild(newDiva);
//    }
//}); 
//document.getElementById('children-2').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
//
//
////Kids Age 3 Room
//document.getElementById('children-3').addEventListener('change', function(){ 
//    var container = document.getElementById('kids-section-3');    
//    container.innerHTML = ''; 
//    var n = 1;
//    for(var i = 0; i < this.options.length; ++i){
//        if(this.options[i].selected){
//            n = ~~this.options[i].value;
//            break;
//        }
//    }    
//    for(var i = 1; i <= n; ++i){ 
//        var newDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
//        newDiv.id = 'element-' + i; 
//        newDiv.innerHTML = "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3'><select name='children1age"+i+"' class='form-control' id='children1age"+i+"'><option value=''>0</option></select></div>";
//        container.appendChild(newDiv);
//    }
//}); 
//document.getElementById('children-3').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label class="search_rooms_input" for="search_rooms_input">Rooms:</label>
        </div>                            
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <select name="total_rooms_search" class="form-control" id="search_rooms_select">
                <option value="1" selected>1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 paddinglr labelform">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 paddingright">
            <label class="labelselect"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 paddinglr">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 paddingright">
                <label>Adults</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 paddingright">
                <label>Children</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">    </div>


<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

Comment: 1) I don't understand the first question. If you run the snippet, you can see that changing the number of rooms from 1 to 2 renders another room. 2) The first thing that might help you is that instead of looping `this.options[i].selected` to find the sleected option, just using `this.value` shoudl give you the value of the selected option, while `this` equals the select. 3) Your second question can be solved by using event bubbling. Instead of binding a `change` listener to each new select you create, just add One `change` listener to the div `container`.

Comment: If one of the selects inside the div gets changed, the event will bubble up to the div and trigger the event on that handler. Then, if you use the event object of the event: `.addEventListener('change', function( event ){`, then you can access the select that was changed using `event.target` . That way you can add any number of extra selects to the container div, but still have only one event handler handling all the changes.

Comment: Sorry if my 1st question was not clear. If you run the snippet you can change the last select option from 0 to 3 for example and you can see new select boxes created. Nut if you change the number of rooms it is not working any more @Shilly

Comment: Aha, I see. Putting the change handler on the div instead of the selects should solve that. I prefer it to the headache of binding / rebinding events every time you add/remove some html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
function children1(e){

var ks1 = document.getElementById('kidssection1');    
ks1.innerHTML = ''; 
var m = 1;
m = ~~e;
for(var i = 1; i <= m; ++i){ 
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
    newDiv.id = 'elementm-' + i; 
    newDiv.innerHTML = "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3'><small>Child "+i+" Age</small><select name='children1age"+i+"' class='form-control' id='children1age"+i+"'><option value='0'>0</option></select></div>";
    ks1.appendChild(newDiv);
  }
}
```

What I did, was just remove the event listener and add onchange function on the select box.

Also change the last option of children select and add onchange function like this:

```
<select name='childrenTotalRoom1' class='form-control' onchange='children"+i+"(this.value)'>
```

So you just have to create 3 different functions or slightly change your code and do it with just one. It's up to you !

So replace this part of code with the function above:

```
//Kids Age 1 Room
document.getElementById('children-1').addEventListener('change', function(){ 
var ks1 = document.getElementById('kidssection1');    
ks1.innerHTML = ''; 
var m = 1;
for(var i = 0; i < this.options.length; ++i){
    if(this.options[i].selected){
        m = ~~this.options[i].value;
        break;
    }
}    
for(var i = 1; i <= m; ++i){ 
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
    newDiv.id = 'elementm-' + i; 
    newDiv.innerHTML = "<div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3'><small>Child "+i+" Age</small><select name='children1age"+i+"' class='form-control' id='children1age"+i+"'><option value='0'>0</option></select></div>";
    ks1.appendChild(newDiv);
}
}); 
document.getElementById('children-1').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```